# How can I make Twitter from the terminal display Hebrew characters correctly?

Tags: twitter, terminal, command-line-interface, hebrew

I've been using the Perl solution for Twitter via Terminal: [IRSSI](http://irssi.org/) + [TWIRSSI](http://twirssi.com/) for the past couple of days. Amazing. The feeling so nostalgic yet so futuristic; beautiful. However, one problem still stands: Hebrew letters result as gibberish:

[image: 2009-09-23_1822]

Any idea how or where to I can modify the script to work in a readable Hebrew?

Thanks, and G*d bless CLI.

Comment: Are you sure your CLI is setup to allow Hebrew? ( UTF8 probably )

Comment: a bit ashamed to admit: I don't know where to check. I do know, however, that Terminal commands such as "ls" results with proper Hebrew file names.

Comment: Is it just Hebrew characters that are jibberish, or any Unicode characters?

Comment: Just Hebrew. Found a serious clue, though (http://adlp.org/cgi-bin/dwww?type=file&location=/usr/doc/irssi-gnome/README-HEBREW). If I get an WORKING answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: Is hebrew working ok in general IRC channels?  Basically, check that your terminal and irssi (and often the screen session you're running in) are set to support unicode. 

Does posting updates in hebrew work ok?

Comment: Zigdon, thanks for your help. I didn't try to post anything in Hebrew (gibberish on CLI). However, I'm trying to install FriBiDi and getting "cannot guess build type; you must specify one". Any help there? (see previous comment link for more information)

Comment: Some progress made: Done installing FriBiDi with MacPorts. Over to installing Hebrew fonts (http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/X11/fonts/); any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit tricky.

#### The Easy Way

You could simply type in IRSSI:

```
/SET term_charset utf-8
```

#### The Hard Way

If things doesn't go the easy way, take a look at [this](http://adlp.org/cgi-bin/dwww?type=file&location=/usr/doc/irssi-gnome/README-HEBREW).

Install [FriBiDi](http://fribidi.org/) and [HebXFonts](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/X11/fonts/hebxfonts-0.2.tgz).
Now, the next part is a kind of an academic *guess*: It might involve some path altering in the Makefile of HebXFonts.

As for me, I did all of the above until it just *worked*.

Good luck.